# Laravel 8 Error No Found : Class "Database\Factories\Backend\AdminFactory"

Tags: php, laravel, git, command, laravel-8

I have this **AdminFactory.php** file in **database->factories** directory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Backend\Admin;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class AdminFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Admin::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

*When I try to run this command :* `php artisan migrate --seed`

it display this error message in terminal :

[image]

Comment: you will have to put the factory in `database\Factories\Backend` or tell the model where to find your factory as it can not automatically find it because of the namespacing/naming

Comment: I don't have any folder called **Backend** inside **Factories** folder

Comment: put the factory in that directory ... then create the directory and you will also have to change the declared namespace for that factory if you move it ... or as said before you have the option of telling the model to return a specific factory, your choice which one to do

Comment: its just the auto-wiring is expecting specific namespace and class names,  once you go against that convention you have to make adjustments ... good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue when trying to use a factory in a package. I solved it by overriding the `HasFactory::newFactory()` method.

```
class LegacyCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    ...    

    /**
     * Create a new factory instance for the model.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory
     */
    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return new LegacyCategoryFactory();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Stumble on this, but redirects to other namespace `Class "App\TestModel" not found` instead of `Package\Models\TestModel`